# Docker's image and host are incompatible

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

I have created a docker image of an asp.net core mvc 3 (preview) on my personal computer which runs Windows 10.0.17134.  My docker files the Windows Server Nano image

> FROM microsoft/dotnet:3.0-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-1809 AS base
>   ...

This image is published to a repository on AWS ECS, and I have setup tasks and services and clusters all OK.

However my container fails to start with the below error:

> Status reason CannotPullContainerError: a Windows version
>   10.0.17134-based image is incompatible with a 10.0.14393 host

I am sure I am running Widows server on the host so why is it complaining that my host is Windows 10.0.14393 ?? That is the version of Windows on my personal laptop!

Answer (score 6):

I got a similar error when I tried to pull the latest windows nanoserver:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809_amd64 
1809_amd64: Pulling from windows/nanoserver
a Windows version 10.0.17763-based image is incompatible with a 10.0.17134 host
```

If I look at dxdiag (run -> dxdiag), then I see that I have:

```
Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit (10.0, Build 17134)
```

So I guess that is where the number from the host is coming. It means that I'm trying to get a container version that is too new for my computer. I found this webpage:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility

There it clearly states that the 2019 version is not supported on my OS. Guess I have to wait! I think that you can check the versions of your laptop and the server and see if they are compatible with the docker image that you are trying to run.

Answer (score 2):

The "host" is the computer that you are running the container on -- so that does refer to your Win 10 laptop, if that's the machine that is running Docker, and is the machine you created the container on.

You probably just need to update to Windows 10 build 1809 (Oct 2018 release).  I ran into the same problem, and I noticed that my machine was still running 1803 -- even though I am taking automatic updates.  I just went to windows update and manually checked for updates.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error because the docker image and my host machine are incompatible.

To resolve this error, first, you need to check if there is any Windows update on the host machine.

Once Windows is up to date, you need to update this parameter in the .env file,  which is available in your src folder.

```
EXTERNAL_IMAGE_TAG_SUFFIX=ltsc2019
```